# Error in php file-Kindly help to resolve

Tags: php

When I tried running process.php file, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: first_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\addemp\process.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\addemp\process.php
>   on line 5

Code:-

```
<?php

echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo '<br />';
echo $_POST['email'];
```

Kindly someone help to resolve this issue as early as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
    label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;} 
    </style>
    <title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>First Name</label> <input name="first_name" type="text"><br>
        <label>Last Name</label> <input name="last_name" type="text"><br>
        <label>Department</label> <input name="department" type="text"><br>
        <label>Email</label> <input name="email" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: is both html and php code in the same page?

Comment: No.I have two different files. first file is .html and other is  .php

Comment: then give the file name in `action` of form

Comment: @affaz:  I tried doing that as well.

Comment: @Saumini:  I have added the code into question section.Please check once and update.

Comment: its working for me..update your question with action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As affaz said: put php file name in `action` in `form`.

Explanation:

Everything works fine if your `index.php` file content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Employee</title>
    <style>
        label{
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
        <label>First Name</label><input name="first_name" type="text"><br>
        <label>Last Name</label> <input name="last_name" type="text"><br>
        <label>Department</label> <input name="department" type="text"><br>
        <label>Email</label> <input name="email" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and `action.php` file content is:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo '<br />';
echo $_POST['email'];
?>
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It is working now.I added if (isset($_POST))